# Calling a sorting algorithm in a driver program

Tags: java, class, sorting

I'm pretty new to java and i have a question regarding the syntax on calling a class file in a separate class file.  So I have the following sorting algorithm:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MergeSort {
   private int[] data;
   private static final Random generator = new Random();

   public MergeSort( int size ) {
      data = new int[ size ];

      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
         data[ i ] = 10 + generator.nextInt( 90 );
   }


   // call this method from main program
   public void sort() {
      sortArray( 0, data.length - 1 );
   }


   private void sortArray( int low, int high ) 
   {
      if ( ( high - low ) >= 1 ) {
         int middle1 = ( low + high ) / 2; 
         int middle2 = middle1 + 1;

         sortArray( low, middle1 ); 
         sortArray( middle2, high );

         merge ( low, middle1, middle2, high );
      }
   } 


   private void merge( int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right ) 
   {
      int leftIndex = left; 
      int rightIndex = middle2;
      int combinedIndex = left;
      int[] combined = new int[ data.length ];

      while ( leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right ) {
         if ( data[ leftIndex ] <= data[ rightIndex ] )
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ leftIndex++ ]; 
         else 
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ rightIndex++ ];
      }

      if ( leftIndex == middle2 )
         while ( rightIndex <= right )
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ rightIndex++ ];
      else
         while ( leftIndex <= middle1 ) 
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ leftIndex++ ];      

      for ( int i = left; i <= right; i++ )
         data[ i ] = combined[ i ];
   } 

}
```

this algorithm should work fine it just needs a main method that feeds it an integer for the size of the array of randomly generated numbers.  So I am attempting and failing to create that driver program.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class Sorting
{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        size=50;
   int[] data= MergeSort(size);

   System.out.println(data);


 }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous What do you think `Random generator = new Random()` is?

Answer (score 0):

Your driver code should be:

```
int size = 50;
MergeSort mergeSort = new MergeSort(size);
mergeSort.sort();
```

At this point you don't have access to the data, but maybe add a `getData()` method to the `MergeSort` class:

```
System.out.println(mergeSort.getData());
```

Or implement `toString()` in the `MergeSort` class:

```
System.out.println(mergeSort);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create an instance of your class like `MergeSort sorter = MergeSort(size);`. Then call the method `sort()` method of the created instance as per I see and get the return value. To print the array directly you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));`. Also change the return type of your `sort()` method to `int []` and return the final sorted array. Overall the corrected code in the main method should be something like following:

```
public class Sorting
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     int size=50;
     MergeSort sorter = MergeSort(size);
     int [] data = sorter.sort();
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
 }
}
```

And the modified `sort()` method will be

```
public int []  sort() {
  sortArray( 0, data.length - 1 );
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the MergeSort class in order to use it. Something like this:

```
  public class Sorting
  {
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
      size=50;
      MergeSort sorter = new MergeSort(size);
      sorter.sort();
    }
  }
```

You'll also need a way to return the data to the caller, like this (in MergeSort class):

```
int[] getData() {
  return data;
}
```